# Entity Framework: migration Column names in each table must be unique

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, migration

Now I have a problem with my source code. I don't know reason. I am using `EntityFramework.6.1.3.`

1. Now, I have a Model folder, and in this folder I have  `Product.cs`. Here is content of  `Product.cs` file.

`

```
[Data]
[Column(TypeName = "numeric"), Display(Name = "ProductUnitPrice")]
public decimal ProductUnitPrice { get; set; }
```

I have a table `Products` is exits. 
I still have not file Migration to add new `ProductUnitPrice` to Products table.

When I run my project, it is automatic insert new `ProductUnitPrice` column to Product's table.

2. However, I want to create a file Migration to add new `ProductUnitPrice` to Products table.

Here is file migration.

`

```
public partial class AddColumnToProducts : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Products", "ProductUnitPrice", c => c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2, storeType: "numeric"));
        }
        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.Products", "ProductUnitPrice");
        }
    }
```

`

But when I run my application I receive a errors message
`Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'ProductUnitPrice' in table 'dbo.Products' is specified more than once. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'ProductUnitPrice' in table 'dbo.Products' is specified more than once.`

3. To resolve above problem, I added [NotMapped] to Model file

```
    [Data]
    [Column(TypeName = "numeric"), Display(Name = "ProductUnitPrice")]
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal ProductUnitPrice { get; set; }
```

I can run application and ProductUnitPrice is insert to DB. However, my problem is I can update data to ProductUnitPrice column. If I remove migration files and [NotMapped], I can update data to ProductUnitPrice column.

What is problem?

I want to have a Migration file to add ProductUnitPrice column and I want I can update data to this column.

Please help me solve it.

Comment: You shouldn't add `[NotMapped]` for `ProductUnitPrice`, I guess you forgot updating database. Before running your application, you should enter the `update-database` command in the Package Manager Console window.

Answer (score 1):

This means you already have this column in your table.

What comes to my mind is that you have set something like this in your migration's configuration file:

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
```

That means everytime you change something in your model, migrations are "updated" automatically.

If so, try setting AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to false, delete migration, run project, then try adding migration again.

Comment: I tried to do it and I got a error message  `System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException: Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.`

Comment: I still receive this message `Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'ProductUnitPrice' in table 'dbo.Products' is specified more than once. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'ProductUnitPrice' in table 'dbo.Products' is specified more than once.`

Comment: there are (afaik) only 3 possible ways why this happens: 1. You added the column by hand, so EF thinks the migration is still pending, 2. You have another property mapped to the same column name or 3. the migration history table got rewritten. Pick your poison.

Comment: Agree with @DevilSuichiro, maybe the best way is to create new database and run command Update-Database (Make sure you haven't declared two times ProductUnitPrice in your model class)